# Returning function value in another function

Tags: c++, function

Thing is whenever I return`reverse(n)` as `value` in `nextPalindrome` function i get a crazy number, instead of a reversed number that I wanted.

My follow-up question is: Is it possible to return function in another function? (eg. `return reverse(n)` )

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int reverse (int input){
     int output;
     while(input>0){
        output = output*10 + (input%10);
        input/=10;
    }

    return output;
    }

    int nextPalindrome(int n){

     int value;
     value=reverse(n);
     return value;

    }

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {
     int n;
     cout<<"n?"<<endl;
     cin>>n;
     cout<<nextPalindrome(n)<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

eg. n=156

output = 236651651

Comment: You have undefined behavior because you never initialize `output`...

Answer (score 2):

output is not initialized 
you should do:

```
int output=0;
```

output in your code can be anything